# How do I change the dialog box title color in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I made the background color of my dialog boxes black. I can't find an option to change the color of the font so I can actually see the titles. There has to be a way, right?

Screenshot: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWtEi.jpg]

Comment: Related: [**How can one make the title bar text/buttons have better contrast on dark colors in Windows 8?**](http://superuser.com/questions/497761/how-can-one-make-the-title-bar-text-buttons-have-better-contrast-on-dark-colors)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to set the title text color in Windows 8.

The title bar color settings are stored in

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM
```

There's no option to change the title text color. The only way to do that is to enable High Contrast Mode and then manually change all of the colors in

```
HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors
```

Comment: http://www.uxstyle.com/ check it out and report me if it do some hack, I can't run it on my system as it give me an error that my laptop's processor doesn't support it.

Answer (score -1):

Please check [this page](http://www.overclock.net/t/1295579/solved-windows-8-any-way-to-change-the-title-bar-min-button-max-button-font-color) out. It appears that most of the options are gone from Wino 8 and so they resort to Registry changes

- Run `regedit.exe` to edit your registry.
- Navigate to the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors\`. It has all the colors you need.
- `titletext` is the one you need particularly. The 3 numbers are expressed in (Red,Green,Blue) format.

Edit: [This page](http://www.windows7port.com/1109/advanced-appearance-settings-windows-8-and-7/) has more information. 
Turns out there two other paths which might be relevant

- `Control Panel\Desktop\Colors\`
- `Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics\`

Comment: it appears those reg settings only work when in High contrast mode. Also, `Activetitle` changes the color of the title bar, not the color of the text. That would be `titletext`.

Comment: serves me right to not read fully before answering. Is it still the case? The thread is a few months old.. I have fixed the key.

Comment: Yup, there is no solution in that thread, unfortunately. Weird how there's no solution for this. Seems basic. And I looked in the registry and TitleText is already set to 255 255 255 (white).

Comment: @KarthikT and John, I just tested all those settings myself on Windows 8 RTM. Sadly, no luck. The high contrast theme did work though; see notes below.

Comment: Yeah, I did try the high-contrast theme. Hated it too much to keep it for any longer than 5 seconds. Damn you, Win8! First Metro isn't optional on non-touch desktops, now this! I guess I'll just have to squint my eyes every time I want to see what folder I'm in.

Comment: hey let me know if the new info works, ill replace the answer if it does

Comment: I just tried changing the values to `255 255 255` for both `Control Panel\Desktop\Colors` and `Control Panel\Colors`, restarted, and got nothing.