# How do I get the colors from Windows 7 "Classic Theme" in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, themes

I've tried to export the theme from Windows 7 and import it to Windows 8, but some colors are still different. In particular, the Active Window title bar color is too similar to the Inactive color.

I've also tried to edit the colors section of the theme file directly before importing it (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). However, Windows 8 seems to ignore the `Control Panel` \ `Colors` section unless HighContrast is set to on. Turning HighContrast on breaks everything, though (text becomes unreadable).

Comment: Does anything [in here](http://superuser.com/questions/497761/how-can-one-make-the-title-bar-text-buttons-have-better-contrast-on-dark-colors) help?

Comment: No, but thanks for the tip. I've added a comment to one of the answers there.