# Change Icon & Window Title colors for Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, colors, themes, desktop-customization

Thanks to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/497761/how-can-one-make-the-title-bar-text-buttons-have-better-contrast-on-dark-colors) I was able to finally change the color of windows active title bar but that is it, unfortunately it still leaves many things to be desired. For example:

- How to change the desktop icon text color
- How to change the clock in the taskbar (as well as other taskbar font colors)
- How to change the inactive title bar font color

Is there not a solution that involves copying someone else's preset settings?

I've attempted editing the registry as other posts have mentioned but so far nothing I've edited has changed anything. I've changed the following thus far:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` > `Control Panel` > `Colors`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` > `Control Panel` > `Desktop` > `Colors`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` > `Control Panel` > `Desktop` > `WindowMetrics`

I was eventually able to get some things to change (after 20+ trial and error restarts), but for things like icons I think I need to change the `WindowMetrics` but unfortunately those are using binary values that I can't modify without breaking everything (never attempt without a backup).

Would be great if there was a public cheat sheet or some form of documentation on the topic since Microsoft wants to make such a simple task so difficult.

Comment: The font colour should be part of the theme I would expect. Exactly how are you enabling this dark theme?

Comment: Right-click>Personalization pick a theme, edit the color, turn down the brightness to get dark version, no text options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one make the title bar text/buttons have better contrast on dark colors in Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/497761/how-can-one-make-the-title-bar-text-buttons-have-better-contrast-on-dark-colors)

Comment: I'd advise [earning some rep](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) and placing [a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on the existing duplicate question. It will garner you more attention that way vs. just posting the same question again saying "I tried XYZ and it didn't work".  If it in fact didn't work, you should at least be explaining exactly what you tried and what the results were (why it 'didn't work'). But again, I'd go the bounty route 'cause this is a duplicate (IMO).

Comment: Thanks, I looked everywhere prior to posting and never saw that so thanks, it actually worked. Also, I will adjust my question because I was also asking about the icon font which this never mentions