# Windows 8.1 - How do I change font color for date and time?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, fonts, colors, themes

I've been looking at [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/497761/how-can-one-make-the-title-bar-text-buttons-have-better-contrast-on-dark-colors/497768#497768?newreg=adf4c489aa254eb8ab0b642d1a76ad1a) and the solution says to save a file as `Dark.theme` with the code:

```
[CLSID\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\DefaultIcon]
DefaultValue=%SystemRoot%\System32\imageres.dll,-109
[CLSID\{59031A47-3F72-44A7-89C5-5595FE6B30EE}\DefaultIcon]
DefaultValue=%SystemRoot%\System32\imageres.dll,-123
[CLSID\{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}\DefaultIcon]
DefaultValue=%SystemRoot%\System32\imageres.dll,-25
[CLSID\{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\DefaultIcon]
Full=%SystemRoot%\System32\imageres.dll,-54
Empty=%SystemRoot%\System32\imageres.dll,-55

[Control Panel\Colors]
ActiveTitle=255 255 255
InactiveTitle=255 255 255
InactiveTitleText=255 255 255
TitleText=255 255 255

[Control Panel\Desktop]
Wallpaper=
TileWallpaper=0
WallpaperStyle=10

[VisualStyles]
Path=%SystemRoot%\resources\themes\Aero\AeroLite.msstyles
ColorStyle=NormalColor
Size=NormalSize

[MasterThemeSelector]
MTSM=RJSPBS
```

Now, this worked fine for the window titles but **does not change the font color for the date and time**, nor for the window previews. It also doesn't work in the file explorer but I'm not hugely bothered about that (unless there's an easy fix).

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

I have outlined the desirable effects in green and the undesirable black font in green. Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: Did you read the comments to the linked question?

Comment: I did but due to my low reputation I couldn't respond. There was nothing in there that appeared to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue now using the following guide:

http://maddada1.deviantart.com/art/Windows-8-default-theme-White-TitleBar-Text-v1-1-347611536

Image:

[image]

Note that even the minimise, expand and close window icons have been made white!

I cannot post the link to the other image (low reputation) but the dates have been made white also.